# access table cell data inside 'div' through 'class'

Tags: javascript, html

Like to know how to read table cells, each cell data is within  . example of table and sample code is here http://jsfiddle.net/ccvq05br/7/
the javascript function is not being called in jsfiddle. did i do any mistake?!

I cant use the id as it is used for other calculation, is there a way to use class name or otherwise ? want to access cell without its id !!

javascript code in jsfiddle is not getting called. is there any problem in my code?!

HTML CODE:

```
<br>
<table id="tableID" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
            <th>Data3</th>
            <th>Data4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class ="data1" name="val1" id="ChkBox_M21">
    </td>
    <td>
     <div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data2"  name="val2" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='1' selected>1</option>
       <option value='2' >2</option>
       <option value='3' >3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
  </td>

   <td>
     <input class="data3" size="4" name="val3" type="text"  id="Txt_M31">
   </td>
   <td>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data4"  name="val4" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='Opt1' selected>Opt1</option>
       <option value='Opt2' >Opt2</option>
       <option value='Opt3' >Opt3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>


  <!-- 2nd row -->

   <tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class ="data1" name="val1" id="ChkBox_M21">
    </td>
    <td>
     <div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data2"  name="val2" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='1' selected>1</option>
       <option value='2' >2</option>
       <option value='3' >3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
  </td>

   <td>
     <input class="data3" size="4" name="val3" type="text"  id="Txt_M31">
   </td>
   <td>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data4"  name="val4" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='Opt1' selected>Opt1</option>
       <option value='Opt2' >Opt2</option>
       <option value='Opt3' >Opt3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>




  </tbody>
</table>


<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Read Data" onclick="callFunc()"/>
```

Javascript Code :

```
function callFunc(){
   alert("hi");
    var oTable = document.getElementById("tableId");

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

        //gets cells of current row
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
/*  get the cell info of first row
    How to get values of each cell which is inside div
    and only can use 'class' to identify specific cells in a row.
    id is used for some calculation purpose.
*/
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(0).innerHTML;

           alert("cell 1 value    :  " + cellVal);
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(1).innerHTML;
          alert("cell 2 value    :  " + cellVal);
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(2).innerHTML;
          alert("cell 3 value    :  " + cellVal);
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(3).innerHTML;
         alert("cell 4 value    :  " + cellVal);

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried getElementByClassName() method? 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: i want calss name for all each columns are same in ALL rows! i can not use document.getElementsByClassName. How can a cell be accessed by getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of the cell and the index of the row to access any data from the table .
exemaple: `oTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(cellIndex)`

```js
function callFunc(){
   alert("hi");
    var oTable = document.getElementById("tableID");

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

        //gets cells of current row
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(0).innerHTML;

           alert("cell 1 value    :  " + cell1Val);
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(1).innerHTML;
          alert("cell 2 value    :  " + cell1Val);
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(2).innerHTML;
          alert("cell 3 value    :  " + cell1Val);
        var cell1Val = oCells.item(3).innerHTML;
         alert("cell 4 value    :  " + cell1Val);
           
    }

}
```

```html
<br>
<table id="tableID" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
            <th>Data3</th>
            <th>Data4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class ="data1" name="val1" id="ChkBox_M21">
    </td>
    <td>
     <div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data2"  name="val2" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='1' selected>1</option>
       <option value='2' >2</option>
       <option value='3' >3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
  </td>
   
   <td>
     <input class="data3" size="4" name="val3" type="text"  id="Txt_M31">
   </td>
   <td>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data4"  name="val4" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='Opt1' selected>Opt1</option>
       <option value='Opt2' >Opt2</option>
       <option value='Opt3' >Opt3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  
  <!-- 2nd row -->

   <tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class ="data1" name="val1" id="ChkBox_M21">
    </td>
    <td>
     <div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data2"  name="val2" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='1' selected>1</option>
       <option value='2' >2</option>
       <option value='3' >3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
  </td>
   
   <td>
     <input class="data3" size="4" name="val3" type="text"  id="Txt_M31">
   </td>
   <td>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" class="data4"  name="val4" id="Data_M21" >
       <option value='Opt1' selected>Opt1</option>
       <option value='Opt2' >Opt2</option>
       <option value='Opt3' >Opt3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  

  
  
  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Read Data" onclick="callFunc()"/>
```

Comment: That is how it is getting used, but i get data what ever inside "<td> </td>" for example. row 2 cell 0 the data i get is "<input type="checkbox" class ="data1" name="val1" id="ChkBox_M21">"

Comment: oTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(cellIndex).querySelector('input,select').value

Comment: you can access it very simple with the query selector and select the input or the select , and get its value

Answer (score 0):

To get the content inside the table cells without using ID attribute , we can use `document.getElementsByTagName("tagName")` or `document.getElementsByClassName("className")` .

For getting the content inside each of the cells in the above example , we can use :

```
function callFunc(){
    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table');   ---- Line Number(2)
    //gets rows of table
    for(var i = 0, table; table = oTable[i]; i++){
      for (var j = 0, row; row = oTable[i].rows[j]; j++) {
         console.log("Content in row" + j+" : \n"  );
       for (var k = 0, col; col = row.cells[k]; k++) {
         var value = col.innerHTML;
         console.log("cell "+k+" value    :  " + value);     
       }  
     }
   }
 }
```

We can also use `document.getElementsByClassName("sampleTable")` in line number 2 in the code snippet , provided a "sampleTable" is the class applied to the table

Comment: my question is wrongly understood, tableId is perfectly fine. Want to access " each Table Cell" which has data within 'div', data includes "input" "select" type, "label" type.  even if is not possible through class name, is there a way to read each cell data

Comment: In HTML each table cell corresponds to <td> . We can access the data inside each each <td> using the code snippet above. You get the complete content inside each table cell. The output would be '<input type="checkbox" class ="data1" name="val1" id="ChkBox_M21">' for first table cell and so on.